# Quantile regression with inhomogeneous density of points

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, linear-regression

I am working on a dataset that can be represented this way: [image: My dataset]

We can see that the lower values on the y-axis are increasing linearly along the x-axis. I want to estimate the coefficients of this linear function, and quantile regression is what seems most appropriate for this. However, as we can see the density of points is much higher on the left-hand side, which gives more weight to this part of the dataset:
[image: Result of quantile regression]

Is there a way to avoid this ?